# PHP : problem rendering zip file

Tags: php, zip, rendering, content-type

```
header("Content-type: application/zip");
$contents=file_get_contents($the_file);
echo "$contents";
exit;
```

The file is about 40 MB. But, on downloading, size is only few hundred bytes. Please help!

Comment: What are those few hundred bytes? maybe it's an error message from the server? What does the logfile say?

Comment: Like freddy said, the few bytes are likely to be some error messages. Open the downloaded with some text editor and see what's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments are correct; it's very likely an error message that will be easily ascertained by opening the file in a text editor. I'd like to also offer that you could use the readfile function to greater effect. See the first example for some good code with headers that gives you a good download. Plus, it'll shorten your code by a line. http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: yup... i viewed in editor.... there was error message of memory being more than php limit.....

Answer (score 3):

Try to set Content-Length:

```
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.zip"');
```